# Drag n drop an element inside an editable div and work on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get an element to be dragged inside a content-editable div and work on a mobile device as well? I have tried many different ways but none seem to work on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to also use [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) can help get things to work on mobile.

Comment: Hey Ric, I am using both of those and no go. Or at least i have not figured out how to use to my advantage. need the element to insert its self inside of the content editable div when dragged on to it.